# Reimplementing Python's enum.auto() for compatibility

Tags: python, python-3.x, reinventing-the-wheel, enum

In Python >= 3.6 there is an [`enum.auto()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#enum.auto) function.

The `auto()` function can be used like this:

```
import enum
from enum import auto

class Fruits(enum.Enum):
  APPLE = auto()
  ORANGE = auto()
  BANANA = auto()
```

I want to use it, but i cannot be sure if i am on Python >= 3.6 so I implemented it like this:

```
import enum

try:
  from enum import auto
except ImportError: 
  __my_enum_auto_id = 0
  def auto() -> int:
    global __my_enum_auto_id
    i = __my_enum_auto_id
    __my_enum_auto_id += 1
    return i

class Fruits(enum.Enum):
  APPLE = auto()
  ORANGE = auto()
  BANANA = auto()
```

It works afaik, but it seems ugly to me. Any suggestions on how to improove it/make it better? or is it ok?

Is there some side effect I may have overlooked?

Comment: What purpose does `i` serve?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The easiest solution would be to use the [`aenum`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aenum)<sup>1</sup> library, which is drop-in compatible with the stdlib and also has some advanced features not found in the stdlib.  It also works in Python versions 2.7 and 3.3+.

---

<sup>1</sup> Disclosure:  I am the author of the [Python stdlib `Enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html), the [`enum34` backport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34), and the [Advanced Enumeration (`aenum`)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aenum)  library.

Comment: thank you very much! i didnt knew about aenum. and thank you for your effort in general on the stdlib and so on; you do a great work!

Answer (score 11):

Honestly, you won't be able to get anything as good as [the built-in code for `auto`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/enum.py#L51). This is as they've added [a clause to `_EnumDict.__setitem__` to handle the class](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/enum.py#L97).

Since we can't make it so that the values from `auto` don't start at one for each enum. Such as the following being equivalent:

```
class A(Enum):
    A = auto()
    B = auto()

class B(Enum):
    A = auto()
```

```
class A(Enum):
    A = 1
    B = 2

class B(Enum):
    A = 1
```

And so the simplest would be to stick with your code, and have the following be equal. (As you done)

```
class A(Enum):
    A = auto()
    B = auto()

class B(Enum):
    A = auto()
```

```
class A(Enum):
    A = 1
    B = 2

class B(Enum):
    A = 3
```

And so IMO your code is good. The only thing I'd change is make your code not pollute the global namespace with `__my_enum_auto_id`. And indent with four spaces. This is as easy as using a closure.

```
def auto_builder():
    number = 0
    def auto():
        nonlocal number
        number += 1
        return number
    return auto

try:
    from enum import auto
except ImportError: 
    auto = auto_builder()
del auto_builder
```

Comment: thank you for your answer! very informative with perfect detail. i upvoted, but i accepted Ethan Furmans answer.

Answer (score 2):

My only suggestion would be to user `itertools.count()` instead of implementing your own counter. Something like:

```py
from itertools import count

_global_counter = count()

def auto():
    return next(_global_counter)
```